# Execute WITH MySQL expression in a query using Laravel db builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Can't find any info on how to execute something like

```
WITH table AS (
    SELECT colA, colB
    FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.colA
),
table4 AS (
    SELECT moo, foo
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.colC = table4.colD
),
......
```

using Laravel db query builder and the expression `WITH`
Does anybody have build such query and have clue how to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible, I use it a lot.

For example, I have a `$query` and I have an array called `$params` (the prepared statements).

Than I do:

```php
$connection = DB::connection('mysql'); 
$connection->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true); 

$result = $connection->select($query, $params);
```

I need the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` since I have repeating `params` (e.g. multiple times `:user_id` in the query).

So basically, I use a raw query. It is possible to also use such a query on an eloquent model, in which case it will return models as you are used to in Laravel. But this example really shows the basic version.